# Postgres+django on kubernetes: django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out

Tags: django, postgresql, kubernetes

My Django app can't connect to the Postgres server on Kubernetes. All other pods are able to connect to this Postgres server and creds are valid 
 as well, any idea why not this Django app

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server:
>   Connection timed out
>           Is the server running on host "postgres-postgresql" (10.245.56.118) and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5342?

Picture of the problem. I login into the django app container and tried to connect via Django's data access layer and psql. Only psql is working without any problems

[image]

postgres:

https://github.com/cetic/helm-postgresql

Kubernetes:

```
apiVersion:  apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    githubdir.service: valnet
  name: valnet
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: valnet
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: valnet
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
          env:
          - name: VALNET_DATABASE_USER
            value: "postgres"
          - name: VALNET_DATABASE_PASSWORD
            value: "gdrBP9xxDZ"
          - name: VALNET_DATABASE_HOST
            value: "postgres-postgresql"
          - name: VALNET_DATABASE_PORT
            value: "5342"
          image: donutloop/valnet:v0.3.0
          name: valnet
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Comment: Do you have any network policy in namespace?

Comment: I append to my post the Kube spec and  I used Psql to connect with this Postgres server and worked without any problems. Only this django app has some problems

Comment: from where you used the psql to connect to it?

Comment: From inside of this Django container and from other containers

Comment: i added a picture of this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That chart configured Postgres to listen on port 5432. You tried to connect to port 5342. Those are different.